# Regex on filtering product line and model number (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to filter out the product line, and product number from varied string. **(Assuming all the product line will come before the product model and model will always contain numbers)**

```
Latitude E6430 (Latitude E6430)
HP EliteBook 8460p (H3S08US#ABA)
ThinkPad T60
```

My expected result:

```
Product line: Latitude

Model: E6430

Product line: EliteBook

Model: 8460p

Product line: ThinkPad 
Model: T60
```

Comment: Why bother using Regex?

Comment: **model will always contain numbers** contradicts itself in the given examples (E6430, 8460p)

Comment: @NickT Since I will be testing different laptop from different vendor. It's the first thing comes to my mind that could filter out the result

Comment: @ZdaR maybe I didn't explain it clearly. could you spell it out for me?

Comment: @Rahul I was doing something but keeping getting duplicate values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for the following regex with `re.search`

```
s= 'Latitude E6430 (Latitude E6430)'
m = re.search('([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]*\d+[a-zA-Z]*)', s)
```

And then

```
m.group(1) # Latitude
m.group(2) # E6430
```

Explanation of the regex is

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]*                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]*                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```

Comment: Should just use `flags=re.VERBOSE` then you can document the regex in the regex `;)`. Pre-compile it with `re.compile` and there's not even a penalty.